# How do I install python through the terminal?

Tags: python

I figured out my problem guys. I had to downlowd eclipse, and it ran through that. `sudo apt-get install eclipse` Sorry about my lack of info. :)

Comment: Can you add more info as to what you have done - with which command did you download it, try to run it, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is installed to all of our computers because it 
is useful framework for a variety of things .

To **use the python** interface from terminal just type `python` .

to **check you python version** just type `python --version`

to **run a python script** you need to type in the form :

`./python_script_name.py`

but very importantly it **has to be executable first**

`chmod +x python_script_name.py`

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

just type :

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

It will show you whether you have newest version of python or you should upgrade

Answer (score 1):

> How do I install python through the terminal?

Python comes preinstalled on ubuntu in all recent releases. You can just type `python` in the terminal to access python 2 or `python3` to access python3.

> I downloaded python through the terminal, but when I went to run it, all I got was a whole bunch of script. Any suggestions? I am using lubuntu

It is unclear how you downloaded it. Normally you would simply run

```
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt-get install python3
```

These really are the ways to install python in Ubuntu. Don't start downloading stuff yourself. It will mess up your system because Ubuntu also uses python a lot for the OS itself. There are some expert ways to install python, but they might be too advanced for you.